# Referencing my SO answers in promotion material

Tags: discussion, self-promotion

I mostly answer questions regarding a specific tool on SO. I also provide professional services around this tool. I would like to use my answers in my own promotion material, primarily by linking to them from my own site. I am **not** talking about referencing my site from my SO posts, it's the other way around.

None of my answers contain anything along the lines of "contact me for further information and a quote" and I have no intention of using SO to promote my services. I want potential clients who visit my site to be able to see a sample of my SO responses as a barometer of my skills.

Is this considered inappropriate use of SO?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with this. That is what done by [Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com), which shows you a list of your top answers, and allows you to choose in which order to show them, and which answers not to show. Those answers are then visible to who watches your Careers profile.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a great use to me. It can only benefit the SO community by driving more visitors to it. It's also a great way for you to show off your knowledge, so it looks like a win-win situation to me.

There's no reason *not* to share your answers, unless you are obviously spamming or something like that. This is why answers contain easy ways to share them on other sites.